# jOOQ into() / fetchInto() maps properties to null

Tags: java, jooq

I want to map a resultset of a simple query to my domain object but when I use the `into()` method then some properties are just `null`

```
Result<DepartmentRecord> fetch = dsl.selectFrom(DEPARTMENT).fetch();
List<Department> collect = fetch.stream().map(f -> new Department(f.getId(), f.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println("collect: " + collect);

// WORKS
// prints: collect: [Department [id=1, name=Mooh], Department [id=2, name=Mooh2]]   

List<Department> into = fetch.into(Department.class);
System.out.println("into: " + into);
// DOESN'T WORK: name is null
// prints: into: [Department [id=1, name=null], Department [id=2, name=null]]
```

Here is my domain object / JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;
}
```

What do I do wrong?

Using Spring Boot 2.1.8, jOOQ 3.11.0, OpenJDK 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a default constructor and the name of the property is dname but I the database column name is different I assume (e.g. name).

> If a default constructor is available and if there are no JPA Column annotations, or jOOQ can't find the javax.persistence API on the classpath, jOOQ will map Record values by naming convention:

https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.12.x/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DefaultRecordMapper.html

Comment: I tried to rename the colunm for testing. It was just wrong in the pasted code here. I edited my post. The property name of the DB column and the JPA  entity are equal.

Comment: Adding `@Column(name = "name")` did the trick. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: I'm happy to help